# How do I convert a multiple SSRS dataset calculation into HH:MM:SS

Tags: reporting-services

I have totaled up the values from multiple datasets and then divided that by 60 to give me the amount of hours. But how do I go about showing this is as a value of hh:mm:ss

For example - here is my expression:

=(count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Authorisation") * 20 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ClaimPaid") * 20 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ClaimPended") * 20 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "General") * 8 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Reassessment") * 20 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ReserveReview") *3 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Trigger") *5 + Sum(Fields!ACD_Calls.Value, "DataSet3") * 6 + Sum(Fields!Extn_Out_Calls.Value, "DataSet3") * 2) / 60

The total answer being 4217. Which then in hours is 70.283 (this is the current value showing) but how do I write the expression so the value is returned as 70:17:00 (70 hours, 17 minutes and 0 seconds)

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works with times <= 24 hours:

```
=Format(DateAdd("s", [YourExpressionToObtainMinutes]*60, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

So you have to change it a little:

```
=Format([YourExpressionToObtainMinutes]/60, "00") & ":" & Format(DateAdd("s", [YourExpressionToObtainMinutes]*60, "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your text box properties to Time, that should help I would expect.
[image]